# Spring Security 3.1 Multiple form login and authentication

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, multiple-login

I'm building a project that provides 2 login forms, one for `member` and another one for `agent`, both of them are different so that I have 2 tables (`member` and `agent`). I want to make login forms for both of them with different mappings. `/pages/agent` is the form for `agent`, and `/` (`index.html` of project) is for `member`. `/pages` is my dispatcher. I have tried many ways without success.

Here's my security context :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/pages/*" authentication-manager-ref="agentAuth">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/agentprofile*" access="ROLE_AGENT" />
    <form-login login-page="/pages/agent" default-target-url="/pages/agentprofile" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout" logout-url="/pages/j_spring_security_logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="agentAuth" id="agentAuth">
    <authentication-provider >
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, enable from agent where USERNAME=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="select a.username, r.namaRole from agent a, role r where r.idRole = a.idRole and a.username = ?" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http authentication-manager-ref="memberAuth">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/member*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/myorder*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/voucherbelanja*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/rewardpoint*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/myreview*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/voucherhotel*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/pages/member"
        authentication-failure-url="/pages/loginfailed" />
    <form-login login-page="/pages/loginfailed"
        default-target-url="/pages/member" authentication-failure-url="/pages/loginfailed"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSucessHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout" logout-url="/pages/j_spring_security_logout"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="memberAuth" id="memberAuth">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, enable from member where USERNAME=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="select m.username, r.namaRole from member m, role r where r.idRole = m.idRole and m.username = ?" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.klik.service.LoginSuccessHandler" />
```

And here's my spring security filter in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do similar thing and failed. So I googled to this post.

What's your problem? what kind of error you got?

From you config, I think maybe there is some problem:

1) You first config, `<http pattern="/pages/*"`
It will match all url start with 'pages', then the member url can not work.

2) in your second config, there are 2 login-form.

3) in both config, you have same logout url. is it proper? I mean, how spring security decide which realm will logout?

Comment: I think the problem is JSESSIONID just created once when you succesfully login, not per-tab. So when i try open the url /agentprofile with member has successfully login, spring security not intercept it and give access denied page because it was detected as role_member not role_agent. The true condition is not denied that page but it should give agent's login form. The problem still unsolve.

Comment: My final working solution is, for 2 http config, set different realms,  like "agent" and "user". for user, by default, the login url will be "user/j_***_check", and logout url will be 'user/j***_logout'.      And if I want to get user info for logged in user, the url should be start with "/user".  And I also need to set pattern for 2 http config.    You set **pattern="/pages/*"** for agent. and this url also match for user's url. So I think the user related security config can not work.